# Lower(field) = Upper(field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL problem.

```
field_1    field_2   field_3
1            1          A
2            2          b
3            3          1

Select field_1, field_2
From MyTable
Where lower(field_3) = upper(field_3);
```

This returns all the records. Shouldn't it return only record with field_1 = 3 and field_2 = 3 ?

Comment: what rdbms are you working with? what's the collation of field_3? some collations are case sensitive, some are not.

Comment: To troubleshoot, add upper(field_3) and lower(field_3) to your select clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled it is ms-sqlserver

Comment: Why You are using lower(field_3) = upper(field_3) condition ? for number detection?

Comment: Do you just want to check whether field_3 is numeric?

Comment: I'm using MySQL workbench and the database is stored on https://www.freemysqlhosting.net

Comment: MySQL does case-insensitive comparisons by default.  If you want case to matter, use `COLLATE`.

Comment: Collate retuns an error

Comment: Be aware, that not every character has an upper/lower counterpart. The german `ß` for example only exists in lower case.

Answer (score 5):

If SQL Server you can set your COLLATE to be case sensitive

```
Select field_1, field_2
 From MyTable
 Where lower(field_3) = upper(field_3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: i tried this and returs an error :
Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS' 0.047 sec

Comment: @NicuMihai Perhaps one of these may help  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx  Basically you are looking for Case Sensitive  (CS)

Comment: @NicuMihai To check the collation on your table, try SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases  Where Name = 'MyTable'

Comment: This is the issue I think. Is about the collation on the database. I think that the collation i used isn't case sensitive.
Thanks @John Cappelletti

Comment: @NicuMihai My default Collation is CI, but in the example, you can change it for a specific query.

Comment: @NicuMihai I see in the comments you are using MySQL.  Gordon mentioned that you can set your collate, but I am not a MySQL guy.